# Endless loading in iphone/ipad browser due to audio tag preload="none"

Tags: jquery, ios, iphone, safari, html5-audio

In my music web sites I have loader on home page. Loader shows endless and infinite loading. On html page there is audio tag with `preloader="none"` like the following:

```
<audio preload="none" ">
      <source src="/static/music/song.mp3" type="audio/mp3" >
</audio>
```

If I use the above syntax, then it is loading endlessly only on iphone/ipad browsers.But there is no endless loading in desktop (chrome/firefox/safari) browser.Problem is with iphone/ipad only.

When I remove the `preload="none"` attribute from audio tag, then `audio` tag look like the following:

```
<audio>
    <source src="/static/music/song.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
```

If I use the above syntax, then it is not loading endlessly.

Why endless loading is happening due to audio preload="none" ".?
I want keep preload="none". Is there any solution?

Comment: The sound won't be loaded with preload="none" - probably your "loader" is attached somehow to your audio and is still loading; are you manually loading the song later?

Comment: no. I am not loading song manually

Comment: Can you then check how your loader is handled? When is it supposed to stop loading?